# How to make a button-click redirect to another URL, in Django?

Tags: html, django

I made an HTML-button, in the code shown below:

```
<div style="" class="button-box" >

    <button>Useradministration</button>

</div>
```

When I click on it, I want it to redirect the user to the /admin-url.

How should I do this? How do I make Django "know" that the button has been clicked?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Is there any reason to not just use a link?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! There is no reason, I guess. Do you mean using the <a href>-tags in HTML?

Comment: Yes. Just `<a href="/admin-url">User administration</a>`

Comment: ok that was easier then I thought! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use like this:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/admin-url">Useradministration</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked :D 

Is there a fast way to make the link invisible? Because I now have a dark blue line under my button (because there is a link on top of it)

Comment: you can use css like this:   
a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

Answer (score 9):

### For button Click Navigation to another URL in Django

```html
<button onclick="location.href = '/pageurl'">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

For a **button-click** redirect to another URL in Django :

```
<button><a href="/admin">Click</a></button>
```

Another way :

```
<button onclick="window.location='projects';">Projects</button>
```

Comment: This won't work for me untill the Click inside the button is clicked. The button click itself won't respond

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="./your-url">
  <button>button text</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value. Furthermore it doesn't seem to differ very much from the accepted answer...